# String apear with dots on the label

Tags: objective-c, ios6, odata

i catch some data from an odata channel with a generated proxy
(generator is from http://www.odata.org/ )

Service:

> ```
> ...
>            <d:prop1>test1</d:prop1>
>            <d:prop2>test2</d:prop2>
>        </m:properties>
>    </content>
> ```
>
> all properties with EDM.string and nullable

generated object is like that (all NSString):

> myData.prop1
>    myData.prop2

i have a tabel-view with a static cell, "left detail" styled and an IBoutlet for the detail label.

> @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel detailLabel;

NSLog print all property values correct. But if i want to add them to the detailLabel some values displayed always with the first character and three dots(v...). That behavior depends on the properties and not on the string length or on the detailLabel.

> self.detailLabel.text = myData.prop1;

If i append a string to the property string with 3 characters ist locks like vvvv... , but the dots never disappears

String formater and the [self.detailLabel setNeedsLayout] dont fix that.

any suggestions?

Comment: Check the real size of the label at runtime. I suppose the UILable is a bit too short.

Comment: it depends not on a label, if I  take another property (with a longer string),then it  works

Comment: Are there any trailing blanks within the String of that property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

That is **Ellipsis**.

Whenever your text is lenthier than the UITextFiled it shows it that way. Like :

`Hi AnoopVa...` in place of `Hi AnoopVaidya`.

Previous answer:

You must be appending the string containing ...

Or you can truncate last three characters from the string, if it is really unwanted and annoying you.

Comment: you don't get it, they are not part of the string.(according to the debugger)

Comment: no, they are like the "label is to short" dots, but the label is long enough

Answer (score 0):

What you see is **automatic string truncation**, there are not really 3 dots in your text string. The string is just longer than what your label can fit on available space.

If you don't want to see/display them, adjust your UILabel width, font size and lineBreakModel. The choises are:

```
enum {
NSLineBreakByWordWrapping = 0,
NSLineBreakByCharWrapping,
NSLineBreakByClipping,
NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead,
NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail,
NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle
};
typedef NSUInteger NSLineBreakMode
```

For iOS5 and older check [UILineBreakMode documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html), for iOS6 and newer check [NSLineBreakMode documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLineBreakMode).